# Flutter - How to save Firestore Geopoint to Json (especially Algolia)

Tags: json, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I am having trouble with saving Firestore Geopoint to Json file. In my flutter app, I save Geopoint like this.

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('ZayyanProperties').get().then(
              (value) => value.docs.forEach(
                (element) {
                  var docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('ZayyanProperties')
                      .doc(element.id);

                  docRef.update({
                    'b18-geopoint': GeoPoint(16.00001, 96.00001)
                  });
```

The value of Geopoint is stored in Firestore database properly. Please see a screenshot of my Firestore database [here](https://paste.pics/9388cee514508b0f4991cc34eab631e3)

My problem is that when the Geopoint is saved to Algolia as Json, it's not saved properly. In the Json file of Algolia, Firestore Geopoint is saved as

```
  "_geoloc": {
    "lat": 16.00001,
    "lng": 96.00001
  },
```

But,  I think its supposed to be saved like this??

```
  "b18-geopoint": {
    "lat": 16.00001,
    "lng": 96.00001
  },
```

Please see screenshot of Algolia Json [here](https://paste.pics/9516954463320922b5577242aed6c30d)

So, my question is how do I properly save Geopoint in Json??

Thank you in advance.
Best

Comment: if you want algolia to recognize your lat/lng, then you have to follow algolia requirements. algolia needs `"_geoloc"` not "b18-geopoint".

Answer (score 0):

For Algolia to pick up on the geolocation data, your record should save the geolocation information into an attribute named `_geoloc`. This attribute can either be an object (with a `lat` and `lng` attribute), or a list of objects with `lat` and `lng` attributes. For example:

Single record:

```json
{
  "_geoloc": {
    "lat": 40.639751,
    "lng": -73.778925
  },
  ...
}
```

Multi-record:

```json
{
  "_geoloc": [
    { "lat": 47.279430, "lng": 5.106450 },
    { "lat": 47.293228, "lng": 5.004570 },
    { "lat": 47.316669, "lng": 5.016670 } 
  ],
  ...
}
```

You can find more information about Geolocation and Algolia [here in the documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/geolocation/).